# Selenium grid can't connect to hub

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to connect to my own selenium grid hub. I'm using Windows 10 for node. Mac for the hub.

I'm running this command on the Mac.

```
 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub
```

and it's getting ready for register node

```
07:08:15.219 INFO [Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
07:08:15.219 INFO [Hub.start] - Nodes should register to http://192.168.1.104:4444/grid/register/
07:08:15.220 INFO [Hub.start] - Clients should connect to http://192.168.1.104:4444/wd/hub
```

then I try to connect to the hub with this command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.1.104:4444/grid/register/
```

it never connects to the hub and trying forever

```
07:10:48.658 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
07:10:48.753 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Launching a Selenium Grid node on port 20519
2021-08-04 07:10:48.885:INFO::main: Logging initialized @648ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
07:10:49.063 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
07:10:49.149 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 20519
07:10:49.150 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
07:10:49.178 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
07:11:10.382 WARN [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Error getting the parameters from the hub. The node may end up with wrong timeouts.Failed to connect to /192.168.1.104:4444
07:11:10.383 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://192.168.1.104:4444/grid/register
07:11:31.415 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration request: Failed to connect to /192.168.1.104:4444
07:11:57.463 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Failed to connect to /192.168.1.104:4444
07:12:23.513 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Failed to connect to /192.168.1.104:4444
07:12:49.556 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Failed to connect to /192.168.1.104:4444
07:13:15.600 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Failed to connect to /192.168.1.104:4444
```

My Mac is still running, But this says not responding...

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Maybe your problem is related to networking; have you checked if your Mac isn't blocking the needed port(s)? Both computers are on the same network? they can see any other running services?

Comment: Hello sir! Mac is not blocking ports. But both computers are on the same network. Should I do something if their computers are on the same network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start your nodes without any additional path after server port. See [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/grid_3/setting_up_your_own_grid/).

Sou your command would be:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.1.104:4444
```

Comment: Thank you for awnsering. I tried that command that changes output a little bit. But still failed to connect. Getting Error like this 07:11:10.382 WARN [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Error getting the parameters from the hub. The node may end up with wrong timeouts.Failed to connect to /192.168.1.104:4444

Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: I tried to connect mac from windows with that command then that works! Thank you so much!